# ASP NET Web Application css scripts not loading anymore

Tags: css, asp.net

I have been developing this app for few months now, and suddenly no CSS Files are loading anymore.

I have not deleted any files.

I have not removed any references in the project.

All i did was restart the App because it couldn't load a page.

I tried reverting all changes, but style sheets are still not loading.

I created an new Template app, copied the references and file over to the preexisting app. Did not work.

This happened few times before, but all i did was copied my progress to entirely new Solution, than it worked for few weeks.

I don't think this is a cashing issue, since style is not showing across multiple browsers (Chrome, Edge, IE, Firefox)

Does anyone else experienced this?
Is there any solution to this.

I was working on the project 4 hours earlier, than i closed VS and later opened it again. After opening VS second time, i was debugging once, and few minutes after that, on the next debug attempt, the CSS did not load anymore.

On the left, my original app. On the right the new template. All references in project are same, all libraries the same
[image: On the left, my original app. On the right the new template. All references in project are same, all libraries the same]

Does anyone know what happened?

How can I restore the default styling of page?

Comment: Can you show how you are referencing css in code & what is error in browser developer console ?

Comment: @PranavSingh For reference i am using <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />. I could not find any errors in the dev console....

Comment: Any errors in browser console like 404 for resources & expected path. It will help you to debug expected & actual path. Is application running on IIS or on debugging?

Comment: I could find following error in console : [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 53ms

Comment: The app is running on localhost

Comment: Is issue occurring in debug & release mode  both while debugging?

Comment: Yes, the mode does not make any difference on the stylesheets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212720/discussion-between-pranav-singh-and-hugo-vrana).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eventually found the solution: my monitor has a image processing feature that tampered with some contents, including my page.